# nHibernate.Search and Lucene.Net 3

Tags: nhibernate, lucene.net, nhibernate-search

nHibernate.Search has last been updated in 2011.  Is this project still active?  Recently, Lucene.Net 3 was released, which is a major version and is not backwards compatible with v2.  I tried to download the source of nHibernate.Search and link it to the latest Lucene.Net source, but since it does not seem to be backwards compatible it is not compiling.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the NHibernate Search is moved to [GitHub.com](https://github.com/NHibernate-Contrib/NHibernate-Search) and darioquintana is one of the member [contributing](https://github.com/NHibernate-Contrib/NHibernate-Search/commits/master) and it's [active](https://github.com/NHibernate-Contrib/NHibernate-Search/commits/master).

Answer (score 0):

nHibernate Search has been updated by **Ryan Barrett** on his fork just some days ago.
https://github.com/ryanbnl/NHibernate-Search/tree/lucen3.3

Lucene 3.0.3 and nHibernate 3.3.3

Comment: Good to hear! Can't really try it out though, because since then I've moved on from NHibernate. Been using document databases over MySQL , which remove the need for such an ORM and I've found ten-folds better.